# Compilation of back-end development programmable file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, reactjs

I am trying to connect a web application with the database with the help of youtube video and currently constructing the database connection javascript file to get the submitted from the form and gets stored in the database. I would like to know where this intended javascript file to be linked to the main part of the code to get compiled and executed. Also, where could we able to observe the output of the backend part of the application. Kindly help me out of this

```
Youtube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZKwrOXl5TDI
Program code for database connection is attached here
var express = require('express');
var router = require.Router();
var mongo = require('mongo');
var assert = require('assert');
console.log("testing");

var url = '';

 /* GET HOME PAGE*/
router.get('/', function(req, res, next)){
    res.render('index', { title:'tournament', condition: true, anyArray: [1,2,3] });
});
/*getting data in the database*/
router.get('/get-data', function(req, res, next){
    var resultArray = [];
/* connection of database to the form*/
    mongo.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        var cursor = db.collection('user-data').find();
        cursor.forEach(function(doc, err) {
            assert.equal(null, err);
            resultArray.push(doc);
        }, function() {
            db.close();
            res.render('index', {items: resultArray});
        });
    });
});

router.get('/insert', function(req, res, next){
    var item = {
        title: req.body.title,
        content: req.body.content,
        author: req.body.author
    };
/* connecting the database*/
    mongo.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        db.collection('user data').insertOne(item, function(err, result)) {
            assert.equal(null, err);
            console.log("data inserted");
            db.close();
        });
    });
    res..redirect('/');
});
/*updating the database*/
router.get('/update', function(req, res, next){

});
/*deleting the database*/
router.get('/delete', function(req, res, next){

});

module.exports = router;

package.json file is attached here:
{
  "name": "Tournament",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Tournament",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "tutorial",
    "donation",
    "example"
  ],
  "author": "zenva",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.14.1",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "mongodb": "^3.4.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should finish the tutorial. That script would likely be loaded in your `server.js` file and used to hook up routes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...I saw the tutorial and they are running the application by reloading the web page or in the front-end, there I couldn't see the output for backend. kindly help me out of this...